# Why does our Elasticsearch/OpenSearch instance return 0 hits if queried on an index without the year/month?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, indexing, opensearch

We have 2 different instances of AWS OpenSearch 1.1. OpenSearch is Amazon's fork of Elasticsearch, and it is compatible with Elasticsearch 7.10 - [it uses the same query syntax and responses as Elasticsearch 7.10](https://opensearch.org/faq/).

Both instances of OpenSearch have the same indices, and data is written to them by month. So for example, one of our indices is named `our_metrics_dev`, but the actual indices listed by the OpenSearch instances (using the `_cat/indices` query) are `our_metrics_dev_2022-03`, `our_metrics_dev_2022-02`, `our_metrics_dev_2022-01`, `our_metrics_dev_2021-12`, etc.

When I query a year/month-specific index, by using a URL such as this:

`https://our-os.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com/our_metrics_dev_2022-03/_search?q=fieldName:"asdf"`

Then I see documents returned with `fieldName` having value `asdf`. This works for both of the OpenSearch instances.

However, when I issue the same query excluding the year/month for the index, by using a URL such as this:

`https://our-os.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com/our_metrics_dev/_search?q=fieldName:"asdf"`

Then I see different behavior between the 2 OpenSearch instances:

- One of the OpenSearch instances still returns documents with `fieldName` having value `asdf`.
- The other OpenSearch instance returns 0 hits.

Why is it that both OpenSearch instances return documents when I query using a year/month-specific index, but only one of the OpenSearch instances returns documents when I query using the index without the year/month?

We have an application that issues queries on indices without the year/month, and we need it to be able to work with both OpenSearch instances. How can I get that second OpenSearch instance to return documents when it is queried using an index name without the year/month?

**EDIT (in response to ilvar's comment):**

**For the OpenSearch instance that is working:**

`_cat/indices` returns:

```
green open .kibana_1                     PcFJzVG_Rue480ziLCH6Tg 1 1       3   0   38.3kb  19.1kb
green open .kibana_2                     dAXksdcwQfyn74mKT_K7FA 1 1       4   0   34.1kb  19.4kb
green open our_metrics_dev_1970-01       Uc0SZvxcTG-KObkmRSKnpQ 5 1      35   0   99.2kb  49.6kb
green open our_metrics_dev_2020-06       yEjqkKL9SaS_UAJhVuQAZg 4 2   33913   0   66.8mb  22.2mb
green open our_metrics_dev_2020-07       8R2CGCefQEegDfI7bs1mhQ 4 2    8191   0   16.4mb   5.4mb
green open our_metrics_dev_2020-09       -G6365AVSxGrZav8or8kkg 4 2   20845   0   36.2mb    12mb
green open our_metrics_dev_2020-10       DkC8VTnTQLiNU7qKe8bs9g 4 2     398   0    1.6mb 554.7kb
green open our_metrics_dev_2020-11       d-ZNIpSqQKyc3JjP8NV5ng 4 2     639   0    2.3mb 787.9kb
green open our_metrics_dev_2021-03       1_6y-7mOSauTvQVB-DuSMw 4 2   60959   0  107.8mb  35.9mb
green open our_metrics_dev_2021-04       k5t37y6RScmg8YYsT6fgug 4 2   37678   0   66.6mb  22.2mb
green open our_metrics_dev_2021-05       VXIec7uFROmBMxV_Z0lI8Q 4 2   28416   0   50.8mb  16.9mb
green open our_metrics_dev_2021-06       oBwLaJuJRrGT6FDBWm0D_Q 4 2   41630   0   74.9mb  24.9mb
green open our_metrics_dev_2021-07       wc3d8PwVTymtJEOVeCO_tw 5 1    9912   0   11.5mb   5.7mb
green open our_metrics_dev_2021-08       0yeYJuqKRY6aCD7QTo4ULw 5 1   10015   0     12mb     6mb
green open our_metrics_dev_2021-09       RQl068KYRkmTNFECEamj5Q 5 1    8285   0    9.6mb   4.8mb
green open our_metrics_dev_2021-10       kBpTRy5qTkGGYXuB8QWaGg 5 1   32858   0   39.2mb  19.6mb
green open our_metrics_dev_2021-11       QeeVgc2cReyyUraGH9Jcsw 5 1 3386031   0    2.9gb   1.4gb
green open our_metrics_dev_2021-12       G644srMwT8CWEQFcBtDzyA 5 1    7959   0    9.2mb   4.6mb
green open our_metrics_dev_2022-01       2Go_a33rSZ23MrufgAVqyg 5 1   22076   0   25.6mb  12.8mb
green open our_metrics_dev_2022-02       UqhC33nkQ3qN7KxfhjhuQw 5 1   15385   0   17.2mb   8.6mb
green open our_metrics_dev_2022-03       Gw7xqdLEQiyP0Qm3I1jnHg 4 2    2697   0    1.9mb 754.6kb
green open our_metrics_dev_2022-04       lF8cjP7JQUWacDJuWGpQYA 4 2     209   0  701.7kb 346.6kb
```

`_cat/aliases` returns:

```
.kibana                 .kibana_2                       - - - -
our_metrics_dev         our_metrics_dev_2020-06         - - - -
our_metrics_dev         our_metrics_dev_2020-07         - - - -
our_metrics_dev         our_metrics_dev_2020-09         - - - -
our_metrics_dev         our_metrics_dev_2020-10         - - - -
our_metrics_dev         our_metrics_dev_2020-11         - - - -
our_metrics_dev         our_metrics_dev_2021-03         - - - -
our_metrics_dev         our_metrics_dev_2021-04         - - - -
our_metrics_dev         our_metrics_dev_2021-05         - - - -
our_metrics_dev         our_metrics_dev_2021-06         - - - -
our_metrics_dev         our_metrics_dev_2022-03         - - - -
our_metrics_dev         our_metrics_dev_2022-04         - - - -
```

**For the OpenSearch instance that is not working:**

`_cat/indices` returns:

```
green open .kibana_1                     QICLgpViRqWGRSYaoKQo4w 1 1       3   0   38.3kb  19.1kb
green open .kibana_2                     chKTFCUdQWCFw-B1Z8N3Rw 1 1       4   0   29.5kb  14.7kb
green open our_metrics_dev_1970-01       NFYOFqDeSG-9fGGJodaxrQ 5 1      35   0   99.2kb  49.6kb
green open our_metrics_dev_2020-06       ddbBqrM_ShWihT3GW1kx5Q 4 2   33913   0   66.8mb  22.2mb
green open our_metrics_dev_2020-07       PGjlVOKYSaSkM8yKNdECFg 4 2    8191   0   16.4mb   5.4mb
green open our_metrics_dev_2020-09       nyPk3lZmR-O9JmzAaw1-vg 4 2   20845   0   36.2mb    12mb
green open our_metrics_dev_2020-10       sJvOBK60QwOmwckfauYtZg 4 2     398   0    1.6mb 554.7kb
green open our_metrics_dev_2020-11       o9q4tl3fRdeAOCjuciXHMA 4 2     639   0    2.3mb 787.9kb
green open our_metrics_dev_2021-03       TrzbLBbgSjmJ13yApMr0Mg 4 2   60959   0  107.8mb  35.9mb
green open our_metrics_dev_2021-04       a6FaC6dLTdO_5lS71owNJQ 4 2   37678   0   66.6mb  22.2mb
green open our_metrics_dev_2021-05       HN64pxgQQ8iEc4C-wmKw4Q 4 2   28416   0   50.8mb  16.9mb
green open our_metrics_dev_2021-06       vqACUzXVSmmbsru1o9sOEQ 4 2   41630   0   74.9mb  24.9mb
green open our_metrics_dev_2021-07       lN5pe6fsSECKCpCnZOdFvA 5 1    9912   0   11.5mb   5.7mb
green open our_metrics_dev_2021-08       UgRhI1OCRHyujYllepPPtA 5 1   10015   0     12mb     6mb
green open our_metrics_dev_2021-09       7VKSt54gTxWfcp8YwTwTlA 5 1    8285   0    9.6mb   4.8mb
green open our_metrics_dev_2021-10       Gu7hmOkuS2m7BwxbLwIkTQ 5 1   32858   0   39.2mb  19.6mb
green open our_metrics_dev_2021-11       vamqNTjiR6Sxc9gtmkQP-g 5 1 3386031   0    2.9gb   1.4gb
green open our_metrics_dev_2021-12       pH5wNcXxRmWJEt3Njg2xJw 5 1    7959   0    9.2mb   4.6mb
green open our_metrics_dev_2022-01       i0WPKRuIRQqr9NasX04E1g 5 1   22076   0   25.6mb  12.8mb
green open our_metrics_dev_2022-02       BH4Cl6uQSfaO-B69L9vEhg 5 1   15385   0   17.2mb   8.6mb
green open our_metrics_dev_2022-03       3_jQ9fV-T1GalKIcq4RaGA 5 1    1573   0      1mb 571.7kb
green open our_metrics_dev_2022-04       4EjBa_rIQXua7223W9DvZg 5 1    1772   0  866.8kb 558.1kb
```

`_cat/aliases` returns:

```
.kibana                 .kibana_2                       - - - -
our_metrics_dev         our_metrics_dev_2020-06         - - - -
our_metrics_dev         our_metrics_dev_2020-07         - - - -
our_metrics_dev         our_metrics_dev_2020-09         - - - -
our_metrics_dev         our_metrics_dev_2020-10         - - - -
our_metrics_dev         our_metrics_dev_2020-11         - - - -
our_metrics_dev         our_metrics_dev_2021-03         - - - -
our_metrics_dev         our_metrics_dev_2021-04         - - - -
our_metrics_dev         our_metrics_dev_2021-05         - - - -
our_metrics_dev         our_metrics_dev_2021-06         - - - -
```

So the OpenSearch instance that isn't working is missing aliases for this month and last month for some reason.

Comment: Could you please provide info on your aliases (`/_cat/aliases`) for both clusters?

Comment: @ilvar Done, see edit.

Comment: So look at whatever is updating that alias (usually ILM policy) . It's probably set up incorrectly in the second cluster.